# Trying to understand the nature of consumer queues with RabbitMq

Tags: c#, rabbitmq

**RabbitMq 3.8.5, C# RabbitMqClient v6.1.0, .Net Core 3.1**

I feel that I'm misunderstanding something with `RabbitMq` so I'm looking for clarification:

If I have a client sending a message to an exchange, and there's no consumer on the other side, what is meant to happen?

I had thought that it should sit in a queue until it's picked up, but the issue I've got is that, right now there is no queue on the other end of the exchange (which may well be my issue).

This is my declaration code:

```
channel.ExchangeDeclare(name, exchangeType, durable, autoDelete);
var queueName = ret._channel.QueueDeclare().QueueName;
channel.ConfirmSelect();
```

and this is my publisher:

```
channel.BasicPublish(exchangeName, routingKeyOrTopicName, messageProperties, message);
```

However doing that gives me one queue name for the outbound exchange, and another for the inbound consumer.

Would someone help this poor idiot out in understanding how this is meant to work? What is the expected behavior if there's no consumer at the other end? I do have an RPC mechanism that does work, but wasn't sure if that's the right way to handle this, or not.

Everything works find if I have my consumer running first, however if I fire up my Consumer *after* the client, then the messages are lost.

Edit

To further clarify, I've set up a simple RPC type test; I've two `Direct` Exchanges on the client side, one for the outbound Exchange, and another for the inbound RPC consumer.

Both those have their own queue.

```
Exchange queue name = amq.gen-fp-J9-TQxOJ7NpePEnIcGQ
Consumer queue name = amq.gen-wDFEJ269QcMsHMbAz-t3uw
```

When the Consumer app fires up, it declares its own `Direct` exchange and its own queue.

```
Consumer queue name = amq.gen-o-1O2uSczjXQDihTbkgeqA
```

If I do it that way though, the message gets lost.

**If** I fire up the consumer first then I still get three queues in total, but the messages are handled correctly.

This is the code I use to send my RPC message:

```
messageProperties.ReplyTo = _rpcResponder._routingKeyOrTopicName;
messageProperties.Type = "rpc";
messageProperties.Priority = priority;
messageProperties.Persistent = persistent;
messageProperties.Headers = headers;
messageProperties.Expiration = "3600000";
```

Looking at the management GUI, I see that all three queues end up being marked as `Exclusive`, but I'm not declaring them as such. In fact, I'm not creating any queues myself, rather letting the Client library handle that for me, for example, this is how I define my `Consumer`:

```
channel.ExchangeDeclare(name, exchangeType, durable, autoDelete);
var queueName = ret._channel.QueueDeclare().QueueName;
Console.WriteLine($"Consumer queue name = {queueName}");
channel.QueueBind(ret.QueueName, name, routingKeyOrTopicName, new Dictionary<string, object>());
```

Answer (score 2):

In RabbitMQ, messages stay in queues, but they are published to exchanges. The way to link an exchange to a queue is through bindings (there are some default bindings).

If there are no queues, or the exchange's policy doesn't find any queue to forward the message, the message is lost.

Once a message is in a queue, the message is sent to one of that queue's consumers.

Maybe you're using exclusive queues? These queues get deleted when their declaring connection is gone.

Comment: No, they're not exclusive. And the outbound exchange (and its queue) is still open at the time I then fire up the consumer. However if I do that I get no message. If the Consumer is alive first, then I get the message.

Comment: @RachelAmbler I can think of message TTLs (a message/queue with a TTL==0 gets deleted if it reaches the front of the queue and there are no consumers there)

Comment: My understanding is that I can set that on the message properties. So I tried `messageProperties.Expiration = "3600000";` but the message still gets lost if the consumer isn't running yet.

Comment: In this case it seems you'd be able to use the management plugin to see what's going on checking the stats for both the exchange and queue: If the exchange shows activity but the queue doesn't, it's related to bindings. If both show activity, but the queue size does not stay at 1 without the consumer, then it's the TTL (either the message's or the queue's).

Comment: I've updated my question with more information. Am I handling the queue creation correctly, or is this where I'm going wrong? I don't issue a `Channel.QueueDeclare()` anywhere - is that my error?

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm not familiar with the c# library enough to know what it's doing under the hood. That being said, RabbitMQ does not have the concept of two-way communication (rpc), that's done by libraries with the help of flags like 'exclusive'. Typically, the RPC-client first declares an exclusive queue for the response and starts consuming from it, then it sends the request to the RPC-server through its well-known queue, including the RPC-client's exclusive queue somehow in the message. The RPC-server processes the request and then answers the RPC-client through the exclusive queue.

Comment: If the exclusive queue is missing at the point when the RPC-server needs to send the response (for example, due to reconnection the RPC-client got disconnected), this response is silently dropped

Answer (score 0):

**Found the issue:** I was allowing the library to generate the queue names rather than using specific ones. This meant that `RabbitMq` was always having to deal with a shifting target each time.

If I use 'well defined' queue names AND the consumer has fired up at least once to define the queue on `RabbitMq`, then I do see the message being dropped into the queue and stay there, even though the consumer isn't running.